# Is there a way to calculate dataframe which depend on previous row item?

Tags: python, pandas

Well, it is challenging for me to explain this question clearly in English...

I am trying to analyze stock and bond market. I need the close value of day `i-1` to determine what I should do in day `i`, which means I will need something like `df.iloc[i, 1] = df.iloc[i-1, 2] * df.iloc[i, 3]`. Just like the picture in Excel shows.

[image]

Now I can only use for loop to handle it. If all the calculation is in day `i`, we can try using `df['value'] = df['price'] * df['amount]` to perform it without using for loop. Is there any similar way to handle this kind of dependent question?

Comment: @gtomer just answered your question, but if you are looking for another *way* of computing your task, I would say define a function and apply (map) on your series. This way of looping is not worth taking your time on a small array manipulation task, but it might be useful if you need to do something complicated ones.

Comment: @KevinChoi Good idea, I will try that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use shift:

```
df['value'] = df['price'] * df['amount'].shift(-1)
```

This takes the amount from previous day